# Centering and restricting a selected paragraph width.

Tags: html, wordpress

On my site I am happy with the home page except for a paragraph that is too wide to read easily. Is there any way I can restrict the width of this (say 500) and still have it display centrally aligned? It's on wordpress and I'm not great at programing so you may need to explain it very simply for me in practical terms. Site is www.explainedwell.com many thanks, Steven
PS if you could also show me how to get the QR code and Impact graphics central that would be great (I put them in a table). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would want to restructure your page somewhat in order to be able to style it more easily, or at least give these specific elements that you mention certain classes so that you can target them in an external css file.

If you are just looking for a quick fix though, you can apply the following inline css styles (to do that you need to go into the page you are editing in WordPress and switch to the text mode there):

```
<p style="padding-left: 0px; text-align: justify; margin: 0 auto; width: 500px;">...</p>

<table class=" aligncenter" border="0" align="center" style="margin: 0 auto;">...</table>
```

I would advise against this though and look for a better way of targeting these elements (as described above).

Comment: Thanks for that I did use that code because frankly that's as much as i know how to do! It was brilliant for centralising the table and the text width setting looked great on the main site however when I viewed it on the mobile version it lost the right hand side of it, so I will have to take the text back to how it was originally unless you can recommend a fix I could do, that's in my scope. Thanks again

Comment: It would be quite difficult to achieve what you are trying to do without some more advanced css - you could for example use css media queries to apply different styles depending on the width of the dispay screen. Unfortunately you won't be able to do it in wordpress where you edit your page, you'd have to edit the css files of your theme instead.

Comment: Thank you, this will keep me going for now, your help is much appreciated.